# Executing Sas Code in schedular

Tags: unix, sas, job-scheduling

I use sas - exceed. I do batch submission with commands on Unix. It will be really helpful if any one can guide me on how will I schedule my task at particular day and time(Say Sunday). The steps that I used to run my query on batch mode are given below:
BATCH PROCESS:

Step-1: Open the unix window.

Step-2: Give Bash command

Step-3: Go to your lib:         cd /sas01/saswork/apollo/shaque

Step-4: vi cd1_41_1.sas (Here VI is the command followed by the file name)

Step-5: cw (paste the entire code).

Copy the code from the notepad and then right click the mouse on the unix window.

Step-6: esc button.

Step-7:         :wq (To write & Quit). /*Your file name is displayed*/

Step-8: nohup sas94 cd1_41_1 &

I have been looking over internet for this, but I m still not very clear. Please help me out here.

Thanks

Comment: You are not going to be able to schedule steps 4 to 7.  You need to have an existing SAS program so that you can automate steps 3 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a separate utility for scheduling, the default scheduler in Unix is `cron`.  I would be cautious about using it, however, if your level of understanding of unix is not very high; it is somewhat difficult to use correctly.

You can read one of many papers on scheduling SAS jobs on Unix, like [Some Tricks to get the best out of SAS and Unix](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/057-2011.pdf), to get all of the details; the short list of details is that you need to have a shell script (.sh) that contains the instructions to do what you want it to do (in this case, what you would have typed into the command line - at minimum, the `sas` call in step 8, and usually instructions to change directory to the appropriate directory for saving logs), and then you need to edit `crontab` to instruct the scheduler (`cron`) to execute that shell script at a particular time/day.

Comment: Well I wrote crontab -e in the unix editor. "You are not authorized to use the cron. Sorry", this prompt came up. What do you mean by separate utility for scheduling.

Comment: Well, if you're not authorized to use cron, you should probably talk to your unix administrator?

Comment: And by separate utility, as with most things on Unix you can use a third party application to do scheduling if you don't like cron.